# Wordpress Related Posts by TAG (Custom Query)

Tags: php, wordpress

:)

So, I am trying to create a "related posts" thing using the TAGS of the post is being read at the moment. My theme -- which was custom designed -- have a related posts, but based on the CATEGORY.

I tried to changed it to tag, but absolutely no success (just a blank screen. ;D)
Can you help me with that? :)

```
query_posts("post_type=any&cat=13&posts_per_page=8"); 
global $wp_query;
$totalposts = $wp_query->found_posts;
$i = 1; 

if (have_posts()): 
while (have_posts()): 
the_post(); 
include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/categorias.php');

$thumb_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'full'));
$class_name = (empty($thumb_image))?("empty_image"):("");
$bigpost = ($i % 9 == 0)?"big-post $catURL":"$catURL";

$terms = get_terms( 'notepad', array(
'orderby'    => 'count',
'hide_empty' => 0
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it. :)

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
if ($tags) {
$first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;
$args=array(
'tag__in' => array($first_tag),
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'=>8,
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
$totalposts = $wp_query->found_posts;
$i = 1;
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/categorias.php');

$thumb_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'full'));
$class_name = (empty($thumb_image))?("empty_image"):("");
$bigpost = ($i % 9 == 0)?"big-post $catURL":"$catURL";
```

And then, after the loop...

```
$i++; 
endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query(); 
}
```